# Yii2 authBearer not working on server

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

i am using `BearerAuth` in my yii2 project and authentication works fine in my local computer but when i uploaded the same code and database on my server its not working and throwing `Unauthorised` error.

I tried to print the `header` on the screen and i can see that there is not `access_token` in header. I am using `POSTMAN` for testing and i am passing the token in header with following token

[image]

Is there anything i am doing wrong? Is there any other way to send `Authrorisation` header on server?

That `access_token` is in the database.I also tried to debug it on server but it doesnt go to the `User` model's method `findIdentityByAccessToken` and throws error before that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem appears if you'r using CGI/FastCGI mode.

This might be helpful to you.

you can put

```
SetEnvIf Authorization .+ HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$0
```

in the .htaccess file to make Authorizaion variable available.

For more information checkout this

```
http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php#114877
```

Comment: where should i add that line of code? i tried to find solution online but could not get a answer.

Comment: Create a file called .htaccess

And write code 

SetEnvIf Authorization .+ HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$0

Comment: That's Great.. Glad to hear from you that solution works for you... Enjoy :)

Comment: **Life saver** Thank you so much. worked like a charm for me.